# PHP-How to create a second menu into a WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Standard way of adding a secondary menu in wordpress.
You need to add the code in function.php file.

Comment: You should really follow the community guidelines Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Add the function to create a new menu open file functions.php and add it:
`register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'yourtheme'),
    'secondary' => __( 'Secondary Menu', 'yourtheme' ),
 ) );`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code into your **functions.php**

```
  function theme_register_menus()
    {
         register_nav_menus( array(
            'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary Menu', 'textdomain' ),
            'secondary' => esc_html__( 'Secondary Menu', 'textdomain' ),
        ) );
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'theme_register_menus' );
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

just login WordPress To add a selectable menu location option in your admin dashboard under Appearance > Menus you need to do what’s called “register a menu.” All it takes is adding a snippet of code to your functions.php file located in wp-content > themes > your-theme.

or add code on the bouttom of **function.php**

```
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('new-menu',__( 'New Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add the function to create a new menu opening file functions.php and registering it:**

```
register_nav_menus( array(
'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'yourtheme'),
'secondary' => __( 'Secondary Menu', 'yourtheme' ),) );
```

**This brought up a 2nd menu in the Theme Menu options.**

Next, add the code to the theme file footer.

```
<nav>
<?php
    wp_nav_menu( array('container_class' => 'menu-footer',
    'theme_location' => 'secondary') ); ?>
</nav>
```